# Installing Vue.js and bootstrap-vue in a docker container

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, docker, vue.js

I am building an application using Django and I decided to base the frontend on Vue.js (also using bootstrap-vue to save some time). I am relatively new to the frontend world and I have been reading about webpack and bundling in general and from what I have read, it seems like it would be better to install vue.js, bootstrap-vue etc. through npm instead of using the CDN. And here is where I run in my first problem, when I install them through npm, the different modules seem to be missing. The relevant part of my Dockerfile and docker-compose look as follow:

```
# Installing other not relevant dependencies
RUN npm install bootstrap@4.5.2 \
                bootstrap-vue@2.16.0 \
                jquery@^1.9.1 \
                popper.js@^1.16.1 \
                vue@2.6.11
COPY "./" "./"
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    command: ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/local/share/src/app:z
      - static:/usr/local/share/src/app/static
      - media:/usr/local/share/src/app/media
      - node_modules:/usr/local/share/src/app/node_modules

volumes:
  static:
  media:
  node_modules:
```

As my project is not JS based, I decided to go without a `package.json` file and just install the needed modules in the Dockerfile. The volumes in the compose file are added so that I avoid having them locally and in my git repository, but only in the docker container. The node_modules are successfully installed in the docker container, however, when I try to add them in my `base.html` template, I get a 404 error. As for how I tried adding them, I tried using the relative path to the node_modules. For example:

```
<script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
```

I suspect that the modules cannot be found because they are missing locally but they are present only in the volumes, but it would be great if I could have them only in the containers and not locally.

Comment: `exec` into the container and check if the files are really there.

Comment: I'd treat the front-end project as a mostly-separate application; _do_ write a `package.json` file for it, since that's the standard way to declare dependencies in Javascript.  Do not use `volumes:` to overwrite all the work the image does, though; in particular the volume mount over the `node_modules` tree will cause Docker to ignore any changes in the installed packages.

Comment: @DavidMaze I also think that it would be a nice idea to treat the front-end part as a separate application, however, I don't have much experience with front-end and I am not sure how to go about it. As for the volumes, if I omit the volume part, then the node_modules will not be persistent and if I do it as a standard volume, then I will end up having the modules locally, which I want to avoid.